# Python: Trouble with comparing two files and making a new file which shows the differences

Tags: python, comparison

I am trying to write  program that looks at two files and makes a new file which shows which lines are different. Both files have an equal amount of lines and both have either the numbers 1 or -1 on each line for example:

```
-1
1
1
-1
```

However the code I have made so far thinks that every line is different and writes them all to the new document:

```
f1 = open("file1", "r")
f2 = open("file2", "r")

fileOne = f1.readlines()
fileTwo = f2.readlines()

f1.close()
f2.close()

outFile = open("results.txt", "w")
x = 0

for i in fileOne:
   if i != fileTwo[x]:
      outFile.write(i+" <> "+fileTwo[x])
      print i+" <> "+fileTwo[x]
   x += 1

outFile.close()
```

Comment: [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) is pretty handy for finding differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this:

```
with open("file1") as f1,open("file2") as f2:
    for x,y in zip(f1,f2):
        if x !=y :
           print " dissimilar lines "
```

`zip()` will fetch individual lines from both files and then you can compare them:

example:

```
In [12]: a=[1,2,3]

In [13]: b=[4,2,6]

In [14]: for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
    if x !=y :
        print "line :{0} ==>  comparing {1} and {2}".format(i,x,y)

line :0 ==>  comparing 1 and 4
line :2 ==>  comparing 3 and 6
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried your version of the code but I'm having trouble finding out which lines are different as it just prints 'dissimilar lines' over and over. Is there a way to print the line number as well?